# Exclude JAR from maven assembly

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-assembly-plugin

I'd like to know if I can exclude a JAR file (i.e. the corresponding package / class hierarchy) from a jar-with-dependencies assembly ?

I know that this can be done by creating a custom assembly descriptor, but can this be done directly within the POM uwint the pre-defined descriptorRefs ?

So far I've test approaches such as:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <dependencySets>
            <dependencySet>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>com.somepackage:*</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </dependencySet>
        </dependencySets>
        <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
        </descriptorRefs>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</finalName>
        <classifier>full-build</classifier>
    </configuration>

    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>jar-with-depts</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

But without success...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, it is not possible.  The above configuration does not work, since `<dependencySet>` is not part of [mvn assembly:single](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/single-mojo.html) configuration. `<classifier>` is deprecated as well.